# Angular mat-select align center to the mat-table row column

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-table, mat-select

I want to align the mat-select field at the center of a table row.

[image]

I used the following CSS code for the column where 3 mat-select fields are added.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <div class="actions-column">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-select>...</mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-select>...</mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-select>...</mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</td>

.actions-column {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

But it does not work. The screenshot shows that the select fields are not center aligned between two borders but are attached to the top border.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should make some changes like this

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <div class="actions-column">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-select>...</mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-select>...</mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-select>...</mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</td>

.actions-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.actions-column mat-form-field {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}`
```